# How to set Richfaces datascoller Max Page Size?

Tags: jsf, datatable, indexing, richfaces

We are developing web based java application. Richfaces used as library.And we have datatable

with datascroller. For now I can send current datascroller index to the backed bean.But the

problem is I can not set **list size** to datascroller(or databable).

Can anyone give a clue?or source please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about pagination, try setting `<rich:dataTable rows="10" />` or however many rows you want.

If you just want to minimize the number of records that are available, just edit your SQL query: `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM foo`.

Comment: Hi Zack.Thanks for your interest. Actually I have java method takes index and Page Size.In JSF I can send that index to the backed bean. But I can not set datascroller pagging size.Do you know how to set it?thanks

Comment: @qasanov -- as Zack pointed out you just use the rows attribute of the rich:dataTable. That attribute controls how many rows are visually presented per page.

Comment: yes sure i know.but my problem is not that. In datascroller we have numbers "1,2,3...10".I want to set these numbers. Lets say i have 120 records and i want to display it 10 by 10. In order to do that datatable row attribute should be 10, and datascroller page size should be 12. My question is how I can set datascroller page size?BTW I am doing server side paging